# Remove elements from array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of arrays from which I want to remove specific elements according to a logical command.

I have an array of arrays such that `galaxies = ([[z1,ra1,dec1,distance1],[z2,ra2,dec2,distance2]...])`and i want to remove all elements whose distance term is greater than 1. Ive tried to write "from galaxies[i], remove all galaxies such that galaxies[i][4]>1"

My code right now is:

```
galaxies_in_cluster = [] 
for i in range(len(galaxies)): 
    galacticcluster = galaxies[~(galaxies[i][4]<=1)]
    galaxies_in_cluster.append(galacticcluster)

where 
galaxies = [array([1.75000000e-01, 2.43794800e+02, 5.63820000e+01, 6.80000000e+00,
        7.07290131e-02]),
 array([1.75000000e-01, 2.40898000e+02, 5.15900000e+01, 7.10000000e+00,
        5.60800387e+00]),
 array([1.80000000e-01, 2.43792000e+02, 5.63990000e+01, 6.50000000e+00,
        5.00059297e+02]),
 array([1.75000000e-01, 2.43805000e+02, 5.62190000e+01, 7.80000000e+00,
        2.16588562e-01])]
```

I want it to return

```
galaxies_in_cluster = [array([1.75000000e-01, 2.43794800e+02, 5.63820000e+01, 6.80000000e+00,
        7.07290131e-02]), array([1.75000000e-01, 2.43805000e+02, 5.62190000e+01, 7.80000000e+00,
        2.16588562e-01])]
```

(basically eliminating the second and third entry) but its returning the first and second entry twice, which doesn't make sense to me, especially since in the second entry, galaxies[2][4]>1.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `galaxies[galaxies[:,-1] < 1]`